# Триггер postgresql

Tags: postgresql, триггер

Смысл: триггер на то, что если в таблице superuser.structurejunction появляется запись у которой assertgroup = 122, то создать новую запись в другой таблице.

Скрипт триггера:

```
REATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_django_pole() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    var_objid INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        var_objid = NEW.objectid;
        IF (NEW.gdb_is_delete = 1) THEN
            DELETE FROM PUBLIC.un_electric_pole WHERE structure_junction_id = var_objid;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (NEW.gdb_is_delete = 0) THEN
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PUBLIC.un_electric_pole WHERE structure_junction_id = var_objid) THEN
                INSERT INTO PUBLIC.un_electric_pole (structure_junction_id) VALUES (var_objid);
                RETURN NEW;
            END IF;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ALTER FUNCTION create_django_pole()
    OWNER TO superuser;
```

Сам триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_arcgis_pole
AFTER INSERT ON superuser.structurejunction FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.assetgroup = 122) EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_django_pole();
```

Проблема: при добавлении записи в таблицу superuser.structurejunction триггер вызывается, но при попытке создать запись в public.un_electric_pole, выходит ошибка, что нарушается ограничение поля not null structure_junction_id (var_objid (и тут показывается прямо значение, например, 34)). Причем записи ни в первой и ни во второй таблице не добавляются. Если триггер выключаю (удаляю, вместо с функцией), то в superuser.structurejunction данные как обычно нормально записываются.

Триггер должен срабатываться after добавления записи, но такое ощущение, что запись ещё не успевает добавиться.

gdb_is_delete - поле, указывающее удалена ли запись. здесь это не важно и не обращайте внимания.

БД - postgresql

Comment: Триггер корректен (разве только не конкурентно-безопасен из-за race condition между exists и insert - используйте insert on conflict). Нет ли у вас на public.un_electric_pole других триггеров? Добавьте определения таблиц чтобы был минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что у вас пишется что-то типо такого "нарушен констрейнт not null при вставке значения 34" ?